# Webscraping with Selenium: Page stuck loading even with Timeout

Tags: r, docker, selenium

I have trouble getting some dynamic webpages to show before I can scrape the css elements.

I'm trying RSelenium on AirBNB, trying to scrape one example listing in San Francisco. On AirBNB, if you click on a listing, it would open up a new window with the details of the listing. I have trouble getting this details page to show.

I'm hosting a Selenium server via Docker with the `standalone-firefox:2.53.0` image.

The R script:

```
library(RSelenium)
url<- "https://www.airbnb.com/s/san-francisco/homes?adults=1"

remDr <- remoteDriver(
  remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
  port = 4445L
)
remDr$open()
remDr$setTimeout(type = "page load", milliseconds = 30000)
remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(milliseconds = 10000) 

#otherwise too fast need to wait for the page to load.
remDr$navigate(url)
#remDr$navigate(paste0(urls[[1]]))

#listings <- remDr$findElements(using = "css selector",'._8s3ctt')

remDr$screenshot(display=T)

remDr$findElements(using = "css selector",'._8s3ctt')[[1]]$clickElement()
id <- remDr$getWindowHandles()
remDr$switchToWindow(id[[2]][1])
price_night <- remDr$findElements(using="css selector","._tyxjp1")
descrpt <- remDr$findElements(using="css selector","._tqmy57")
parking <- remDr$findElements(using="css selector","._6c4wvw")
```

It does not matter how much ms I set in `remDr$setTimeout`. The details page would not show. Calling `remDr$screenshot(display=TRUE)` yields the following image:

[image]

Which seems to suggest that the webpage failed to load fully before I started finding the CSS elements that I'm trying to scrape.

An excerpt of the log on the Selenium server is attached:

```
19:30:05.490 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{nativeEvents=true, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, version=, platform=ANY}]])
19:30:05.491 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{nativeEvents=true, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, version=, platform=ANY}]
19:30:06.810 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{nativeEvents=true, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, version=, platform=ANY}]]
19:30:18.650 INFO - Executing: [page load wait: 30000])
19:30:18.655 INFO - Done: [page load wait: 30000]
19:30:20.084 INFO - Executing: [implicitly wait: 10000])
19:30:20.089 INFO - Done: [implicitly wait: 10000]
19:30:26.267 INFO - Executing: [delete session: 5da351c5-bd0e-4a95-a357-c049b71ed680])
19:30:26.377 INFO - Done: [delete session: 5da351c5-bd0e-4a95-a357-c049b71ed680]
19:30:58.763 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{nativeEvents=true, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, version=, platform=ANY}]])
19:30:58.764 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{nativeEvents=true, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, version=, platform=ANY}]
19:30:59.913 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{nativeEvents=true, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, version=, platform=ANY}]]
19:31:00.922 INFO - Executing: [page load wait: 30000])
19:31:00.927 INFO - Done: [page load wait: 30000]
19:31:01.675 INFO - Executing: [implicitly wait: 10000])
19:31:01.680 INFO - Done: [implicitly wait: 10000]
19:31:03.800 INFO - Executing: [get: https://www.airbnb.com/s/san-francisco/homes?adults=1])
19:31:05.301 INFO - Done: [get: https://www.airbnb.com/s/san-francisco/homes?adults=1]
19:31:10.700 INFO - Executing: [find elements: By.cssSelector: ._8s3ctt])
19:31:10.741 INFO - Done: [find elements: By.cssSelector: ._8s3ctt]
19:31:10.806 INFO - Executing: [click: 0 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on LINUX (1741f648-be7b-48e0-96c9-0c1d2e14a498)] -> css selector: ._8s3ctt]])
19:31:10.962 INFO - Done: [click: 0 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on LINUX (1741f648-be7b-48e0-96c9-0c1d2e14a498)] -> css selector: ._8s3ctt]]
19:31:14.947 INFO - Executing: [get window handles])
19:31:14.950 INFO - Done: [get window handles]
19:31:15.860 INFO - Executing: [switch to window: {679b54f5-ec42-4ba6-8939-cb7b0d40a7b9}])
19:31:15.864 INFO - Done: [switch to window: {679b54f5-ec42-4ba6-8939-cb7b0d40a7b9}]
19:31:20.580 INFO - Executing: [find elements: By.cssSelector: ._tyxjp1])
19:31:30.592 INFO - Done: [find elements: By.cssSelector: ._tyxjp1]
19:31:44.099 INFO - Executing: [take screenshot])
19:31:44.145 INFO - Done: [take screenshot]
```

I don't see anything wrong on the server side, but I might be wrong.

Is the timeout really implemented? If not, is there another way that I can get the page to fully load before I scrape?

Comment: Timeout generally tells the system when to stop trying to load a page. It doesn't tell the system how long to wait for a page to load. Perhaps try `Sys.sleep()` in R instead?

Comment: I was able to load the page without docker in firefox..

Comment: @NadPat Yeah, I can't do that. For some reason I can only get it to work with a Docker server. Running `rsDriver` just yields `Error in .Object$initialize(...) : 
  formal argument "browserName" matched by multiple actual arguments`. I tried upgrading my Java SDK but no luck with that.

Comment: @AdamSampson Thanks for this, but it doesn't work. I put a `Sys.sleep(5)` in after the first `navigate()` call and after the `$clickElement()` call with no luck. It's showing the same result as above.

Comment: Your above link `https://www.airbnb.com/s/san-francisco/homes?adults=1` redirected me to this `https://www.airbnb.co.in/s/san-francisco/homes?adults=1&locale=en&_set_bev_on_new_domain=1632025812_YjZhNTk3ZjAyOTI3`. I was able to open it in Docker.

Comment: @NadPat Yes. I could get the first page to show, but not the listing details, i.e. clicking on the listings, switching to the popped up window and scrape from that new page

Comment: @KyleChan there is more redirects in the page. Are you sure you are following all of them? all of the listings redirect to another webpage again. for example, `https://www.airbnb.co.in/rooms/45224017?adults=1&previous_page_section_name=1000&federated_search_id=c5815cb4-858a-4570-814e-d4bf3ddd6a0a` redirects to:
`https://www.airbnb.co.in/rooms/45224017?adults=1&federated_search_id=c5815cb4-858a-4570-814e-d4bf3ddd6a0a&source_impression_id=p3_1638600612_8tCcPu2vuWfACDR6&guests=1`

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to extract information from the web page with the following code :

```
library(RSelenium)
shell('docker run -d -p 4446:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4446L, browserName = "firefox")

remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.airbnb.com/s/san-francisco/homes?adults=1")

web_Obj <- remDr$findElement("xpath", '/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]')
web_Obj$getElementText()

[[1]]
[1] "Hotel room in Nob Hill"
```